# Java use of ? in generic programming

Tags: java, generics

Consider these 2 instance functions:

```
public  <T> void f1 (List<? extends Object>  a) {
    System.out.println(a); 
}

public void f2 (<? extends Object>  a) {
    System.out.println(a); 
}
```

The first function is accepted while the second gets an error mark
`Syntax error on token "(", Type expected after this token`

I can't understand the reason why. Can someone help me?

Edit:
Let me rephrase all. 
I have a class

```
package pk1;
public class Gencla<T> {
    public T alfa;
}
```

and a Test class

```
package pk1;
public class Test {
    public void f1 ( Gencla<? extends Object>  a ) {
        System.out.println(a.alfa); 
    }
    public void f2 ( <? extends Object>  a ) {
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

In both functions f1 and f2, what is going to be printed is something whose Type is "? extends Object".
Why does the compiler place a mark on the f2 ?

Comment: You Need to add a type of hich the generic is. In first case a it is a `List`

Comment: [rtfm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: You need to specify List in `public  <T> void f2 ( <? extends Object>  a ) {` . You're missing that and directly have a parenthesis opening out. Check after f2(...

Comment: Reference types are already polymorphic, just use `Object` as the type of the parameter.

Comment: I'd like to stess that the error is not about generic programming. Java complains that the Type is missing. Well, the Type is an Object or whatever inherits it. That's the Type. So, why the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your f2 function:

```
public <T> void f2 ( <? extends Object>  a ) {
    System.out.println(a); 
}
```

fails do define a type argument. The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.
Instead, it is used to limit or extend existing collection or a generic type, so less or more types can be used for it.

```
public <T extends Object> void f2 ( T a ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: …but `<T extends Object> void f2(T a)` has no advantage over a straight-forward `void f2(Object a)`…

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
public <T extends Object> f2 (T a) {
}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to do. 
A function that accepts anything that extends an object. 
(The reason why someone would ever want to do this, is another thing).
Since I will never use T again, why can't be accepted ?